# Problem using `having`: in MySQL it's working fine but unable to use in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the `inventories` which are stocked.

```
$inv = DB::table('inventories')             
       ->havingRaw('Coalesce(inventories.inv_hold, 0) + 
      Coalesce(inventories.inv_sold, 0) + Coalesce(inventories.inv_return, 0), >, inventories.quantity')
      ->get();
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Can't find my error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well 9 out of the 10 times having is used with GROUP BY.. Maybe Laraval needs to have a group by function also which goes against ANSi SQL because in ANSI SQL its defined having can be used without group by

Comment: Besides why not convert this query into using a where instead? Should give the same results then this query

Comment: where is not producing the result.... i just needed sub query ..

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I followed a blog which showed having `,` in `havingRaw`.